# Laravel 5 настройка путь к public

Tags: php, laravel

У меня есть проект **site.ru**.

Я залил в папку **site.ru/blog** проект с **laravel**. Но проблема в том, что сам laravel будет доступен, только если зайти в **site.ru/blog/public**.

Как сделать так, чтобы он был доступен по ссылке **site.ru/blog**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте с помощью `.htaccess`

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^blog/public/$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/blog/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^blog/$ /blog/public/ [L]
```